# AngularJS undefined Controller using require

Tags: javascript, angularjs, require

I am using requireJS in my application.

Whenever i tried to register controller on my module it said that the controller is not defined. Here is my controller which resides on login.controller.js

```
function LoginController() {

}
```

and here's my module code:

```
require('angular')
require('@uirouter/angularjs');
require('./service/storage')
require('./controller/login.controller')

angular.module('SecurityModule', ['ui.router'])
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

// Routing
    angular.module('SecurityModule')
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

            $stateProvider.state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/app/resources/view/security/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
            });
        })
    ;
```

When i checked my bundled.js the declaration of LoginController appears first. So why is it still undefine?

Thanks.

NOTE that im using browserify (which then uses commonJS) to bundle my files.

Comment: Apparently what i've done is to assign it to variable like so: var LoginController = require(....);

Answer (score -1):

As the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/guide/module) states:

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get
>   applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
>   simplest form the module consist of collection of two kinds of blocks:
>
> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. **Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks.** This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
config(function(injectables) { // provider-injector
  // This is an example of config block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
  // into config blocks.
}).
run(function(injectables) { // instance-injector
  // This is an example of a run block.
  // You can have as many of these as you want.
  // You can only inject instances (not Providers)
  // into run blocks
});
```

Comment: that doesn't appear to be the problem;  they aren't trying to inject the controller into the config block at all here.